# How to configure HAProxy so that requests with a different destination IP address is handled by HAProxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy

I have 2 EC2 instances.

1. HAProxy server listening on port 80 `x.x.0.79`
2. Client - meant to just send curl commands and test. `x.x.0.12`

I am using AWS Route Tables to redirect any requests in my VPC with a destination of `x.x.0.35` to be routed to the HAProxy box `x.x.0.79`.

I am sending curl commands to `curl x.x.0.35` from the 2nd EC2 box `x.x.0.12`

When I `curl x.x.0.35`, I can see traffic hitting the HAProxy box `x.x.0.79` by monitoring `tcpdump -qn -s 0 -A port 80`.

However, the HAProxy server is not receiving those requests. The requests are just timing out. They are not even hitting the default backend.

This is my haproxy.cfg.

```
defaults
  mode http
  timeout client 10s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 10s
  timeout http-request 10s

frontend myfrontend
  bind :80

  acl source_ip_a src x.x.x.121
  acl source_ip_b src x.x.0.235

  acl destination1 dst x.x.0.35

  use_backend backend_a if source_ip_a
  use_backend backend_b if source_ip_b

  use_backend backend_a if destination1

  default_backend temp

backend backend_a
    server destination_a x.x.0.57:8000

backend backend_b
    server destination_b x.x.0.178:8000

backend temp
    server destination_c 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.